# I can't move the buttons to the bottom - JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I tried using GridLayout and BorderLayout but could not make my Buttons go below the mouth of the dog (picture). After making the button below the dog mouth, how do I add function to the buttons? For Settings, how do I make it open another window after I clicked on it and I can close the settings window instead of the whole thing. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Codegi extends JFrame {

    public Codegi() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        try {
            frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("enter image description here[1]")))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p1.setOpaque(false);
        p2.setOpaque(false);
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 20));

        //JButton b1 = new JButton("START");
        //JButton b2 = new JButton("SETTINGS");
        p2.add(p1);
        p1.add(new JButton("SETTINGS"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(new JButton("START"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //p1.add(b1);
        //p1.add(b2);

        frame.add(p2);

        //design of button
        //Font largefont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
        //b1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        //b2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        //b1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //b1.setFont(largefont);
        //b2.setFont(largefont);
        frame.setTitle("Codegi:Programming made fun");
        frame.setSize(498, 687);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(467, 627);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Codegi();
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxPAl.png)

Comment: "_how do I make it open another window after I clicked on it_" Add listener to that button

Comment: *"For Settings, how do I make it open another window after I clicked on it and I can close the settings window instead of the whole thing."* That is one, or perhaps two, separate questions beyond the one mentioned in the title. They should be on a separate question & answer thread(s).

Comment: sorry >< kind of new to this. They asked me to describe more on the question but i have no idea what to write, so i just bomb in other stuff

Comment: `frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon
    (ImageIO.read(new File                             
    ("enter image description here[1]")))));` As an aside, trying to use a label as a background for a GUI has multiple problems. I'd custom paint the BG to a `JPanel` that will allow the GUI to be sized and laid out according to the components it contains, the layout and the layout constraints used to add the components.

Comment: Try `GroupLayout` for the `frame` panel. It is quite flexible than `GridLayout` & `BorderLayout` layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout to null
view.setLayout(null);
and then set the position of buttons like below
btn.setBounds(starting x-coordinate,starting y-coordinate,btn width,btn height);
remove panels by setVisible(false);
and show new ones with setVisible(true); on btn click event

Comment: set Layout to null is bad practice and not recommended